# What to do about memory warnings and memory errors in a cordova, ionic, angular hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, memory-management, inappbrowser, ionic-framework

I have an angular/hybrid app that is receiving Memory warnings when using the inappbrowser to open links.  Particularly when the linked page has a video player.  I can see in xcode the memory usage approaching 300Meg.  On occasion this causes a memory error that will crash the app.  If I allow the link to open outside of my app in Safari,  I spare the memory and the app receives far fewer memory errors and saves 100's of Meg of memory.

The real question is what to do in general when getting a memory error for an app that is largely written in Javascript where besides following best practices (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) for enabling garbage collection to occur,  you don't have explicit control over garbage collection.

Any guidance here would be helpful.  I would very much prefer to use the in-app browser rather than leave the app and open in Safari.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I do receive memory warnings and sometimes app crashes. I do not know how to handle didReceiveMemoryWarning.